# can I install ubuntu for tablet on my galaxy tab 2 and where can I get it

Tags: tablet

I have been watching the Canonical ads for Ubuntu Touch on tablet and I am very impressed, however can it be installed on my galaxy tab 2 GT-P5100?

If so where can I get it? How much does it cost? How do I do the install?

I am currently running Ubuntu 12 point something via the linuxonandroid install chroot method and while it is fantastic the features claimed by Ubuntu touch look too good not to try.

Comment: Visit the [Ubuntu Touch Devices wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) and search for "Samsung Galaxy Tab 2".

Answer (score 0):

I believe everything you need to know is here http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet

The Ubuntu version for tablet is not out yet but is looking for developers seen as Ubuntu is open source.